# Access 365 - Suppress Active Content Warning Popup

Tags: security, office365, microsoft-access

**POPUP - THE FOLLOWING POST CONCERNS THE DISRUPTIVE POPUP NOT THE MESSAGE BAR**

Starting with Microsoft 365 for Apps update 16.0.16130.20218, Microsoft changed the functionality of Access 365 so that every time I open a database from an untrusted location I see the **popup** below.

**POPUP BELOW - THIS IS THE ISSUE -- HOW TO DISABLE DISRUPTIVE POPUP**
[image]

Is there a setting somewhere that will disable this **popup**.

I am aware that I can make this a trusted location.  That's not what I want to do. I want to keep this location untrusted and stop seeing this message every time I open a DB.

**PS:**  I also see the disruptive **popup** if I export a table/query from database A to database B.  If database B contains blocked active content, the disruptive **popup** occurs right in the middle of the export and demands to be clicked.  Why?  For what purpose?

**PS2:** Not every untrusted database on my machine triggers the popup.  Some can be opened that only display the Security Warning in the yellow bar at the top of the screen.

I varied the following items in a DB that does not trigger the **popup** and NONE of the following things triggered it.

- Add a Macro
- Add a Module
- Add a Linked Table

None of the things above caused the popup to trigger.

**PS3:** I copied two different Access 2000 - 2003 version mdbs to my desktop, so these are new databases in the same directory.  Neither DB has its active content enabled.  They both display the Security Warning in the yellow bar at the top of the page.  Same DB version, same directory, same active content setting, but one triggers the **popup** and another does not.  Wuh?

Comment: @Ramhound - Do you have a guess as to why this occurs on some blocked databases and not all?  I would think this type of popup occurred for a reason but it looks an issue with the latest Office update.

Comment: @EllieK - I have not been able to reproduce the behavior you describe in your question and I have the current version of Office 365 (Access) installed on my system. Why are you unable to adjust the Tust Settings?

Comment: @Ramhound - Long story short -- These databases are in a .Net bin folder.  After compiling and launching my .Net app, they contain populated temp tables which are necessary for executing the queries for debugging.  They are also moved anew to the bin folder every time I compile.  So every time I open the database its active content is turned off.  My question is why did Microsoft feel the need to add the disruptive popup.  There is no way to remove it.  I get a message in my info bar and I also get a disruptive popup that demands a click.  Why do I need both?  Do you see the popup or not?

Comment: I copied two different Access 2000 - 2003 version mdbs to my desktop so these are new databases in the same directory.  Neither DB has its active content enabled.  They both display the Security Warning in the yellow bar at the top of the page.  Same DB version, same directory, same active content setting, but one triggers the popup and another does not.  Wuh?

Comment: "My question is why did Microsoft feel the need to add the disruptive popup." - Demand from customers to provide notifications of potentially unsafe actions.

Comment: @Ramhound - But opening a database with the Active Content disabled is not an **unsafe** action.  It is the safe action.  It is the default action.  Have you read my posts?  Do you understand what I'm asking?  The popup warns me that I'm taking a **safe** action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General Advice

Confirm that you suppress via the "trusting the location" method as talked about in the [Add, remove, or change a trusted location in Microsoft Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-in-microsoft-office-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4) post.

If your development path has a super long path over the 255 character to the full file name, or you have folder path with weird characters or maybe even dots, etc. see if you can copy it to a simple folder and add that path to test in case it's related to something like that.

> **Note:** MS Access 365 could have setting corruption and it may not be able to trust the path and never becoming effective to
> trust the location(s) you tell it to trust.

Close Access and confirm all memory instances of it are killed after you close it when you add the new shorter trusted test path if you can and that's applicable on the local C drive for testing.

If it's on a separate or attached partition, there can be NTFS security issues with those configurations sometimes. But kill all `MSAccess.exe` instances running in memory from Task Manager's `Details` tab after closing it before and/or after you save the trusted path.

Depending on computer and/or other policies it may get if you're in a domain/corporate environment, it could be something pushed to your machine that the sysadmin that maintains AD, GPOs, and other things would need to look at adjusting for you too.

> ### Add a trusted location
>
> 1. In your Office app, click **File** > **Options**.
> 2. Click **Trust Center** > **Trust Center Settings** > **Trusted Locations**.
> 3. Click **Add new location**.
> 4. Click **Browse** to find the folder, select a folder, and then click **OK**.
>
> ### Remove a trusted location
>
> 1. In your Office app, click **File** > **Options**.
> 2. Click **Trust Center** > **Trust Center Settings** > **Trusted Locations**.
> 3. Select the location to be removed, and then click **Remove**, and then click **OK**.
>
> ### Change a trusted location
>
> 1. In your Office app, click **File** > **Options**.
> 2. Click **Trust Center** > **Trust Center Settings** > **Trusted Locations**.
> 3. In the **Trusted Locations** list, select a location, and then click **Modify**.
> 4. Make the modifications you want, and then click **OK**.
>
> [Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-in-microsoft-office-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4).

Furthermore, this doesn't seem to be a bug and is rather a security feature that is working per the default configuration with Access 365 by design as according to [Enable or disable security alerts on the Message Bar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/enable-or-disable-security-alerts-on-the-message-bar-adbf15d9-9195-4498-bdc3-5cb0dfe93852).

> ## [Enable or disable security alerts on the Message Bar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/enable-or-disable-security-alerts-on-the-message-bar-adbf15d9-9195-4498-bdc3-5cb0dfe93852)
>
> The Message Bar displays security alerts when there is potentially
> unsafe active content (such as macros, ActiveX controls, **data
> connections and so on**) in the file that you want to open. Or, you
> may have a read-only file that you ready to edit and need to enable
> editing. In such cases, the Message Bar appears, yellow or red, with a
> shield icon, to alert you about potential problems. If you know the
> content is from a reliable source, on the yellow Message Bar, you can
> click Enable Content to enable content to make it a trusted document
> or enable content for a session. On the red Message Bar, you can click
> the warning text. In the Office Backstage view, the view that you see
> when you click the File tab, you can click Edit Anyway.
>
> #### Enable or disable security alerts on the Message Bar
>
> 1. In an Office program, click the **File** tab.
> 2. Click **Options**.
> 3. Click **Trust Center**, and then click **Trust Center Settings**.
> 4. Click **Message Bar**. The Message Bar Settings for all Office Applications dialog box appears.
>
>    - **Show the Message Bar in all applications when document content is blocked**     ***This is the default***. The Message Bar appears
>      when potentially unsafe content has been disabled.
>
>      **Note:** The option is not selected, and the Message Bar does not appear, if you select Disable all macros without notification in
>      the Macro Settings area of the Trust Center.
>
> - **Never show information about blocked content**     This option disables the Message Bar and no alerts appear about security issues,
>   regardless of any security settings in the Trust Center.
>
> **Note:** Changing the Message Bar options in the Trust Center does not change the Protected View Message Bar.
>
> [Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/enable-or-disable-security-alerts-on-the-message-bar-adbf15d9-9195-4498-bdc3-5cb0dfe93852)

Lastly, as according to [Active content types in your files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/active-content-types-in-your-files-b7ff2e8a-4055-47d4-8c7d-541e19f62bea) it's also indicated here that this is a security feature default that's turned on by design so it's working and prompting as expected.

> ### [Active content types in your files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/active-content-types-in-your-files-b7ff2e8a-4055-47d4-8c7d-541e19f62bea)
>
> Active content is additional functionality in a file or program, such
> as macros, add-ins, or data connections. This article lists types of
> active content that can be blocked by settings in Trust Center and
> which, when present in a document, cause display of the Message Bar
> when you open your file.
>
> #### Check files by using Trust Center
>
> In Trust Center, you can configure checks of content in files for
> computer viruses or other security hazards that can be delivered to
> your computer by active content. **These checks prevent active content
> from running automatically, which helps to protect your computer and
> network by preventing unexpected or malicious content from running.**
>
> To learn more about Trust Center, see [View my options and settings in
> the Trust
> Center](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-my-privacy-options-in-the-microsoft-office-trust-center-d672876e-20d3-4ad3-a178-343d044e05c8).
>
> **To open Trust Center in an Office program**
>
> 1. Click **File**, and then click **Options**.
> 2. Click **Trust Center**, and then click **Trust Center Settings**.
>
> #### Types of active content
>
> To see the types of active content that are blocked, click **Trust
> Center Settings** to open the **Trust Center** window.
>
> [Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/active-content-types-in-your-files-b7ff2e8a-4055-47d4-8c7d-541e19f62bea)

---

## OP Solution

> The issue was, no matter how I removed or applied trust to the
> folders in my bin directory, the DB always opened with the popup.
>
> Eventually I **deleted my whole bin directory, removed all existing
> trusted locations and rebooted.** Then I **recreated the
> trusted locations, recompiled, and rebuilt the bin directory**.
>
> Everything works as expected now. **There was something corrupting the
> existing structure/trust. Rebuilding both fixed it!** –
> [EllieK](https://superuser.com/users/894185/elliek)